# Scheduling Reports w/ Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

So I'm new to Crystal Reports and have a report that the developer before me developed. I'd like to go in and adjust the settings so that the report is sent at a different time.

Any ideas as to how I would go about this? Or any ideas as to how a report could be scheduled?

Comment: How is the report currently scheduled?

Comment: Are you using BusinessObjects Enterprise?

Comment: @MarkBannister I'm not sure. I'm pretty sure he used a feature in Crystal Reports to schedule the report. Would that be possible?

Comment: @craig I'm not sure. How could I find out?

Comment: @Drew: Not so far as I know - which version of Crystal are you using?

Comment: @MarkBannister: Gotcha. CR Professional, v. 8.5.0.217?

Comment: In CR v8.5, Crystal Enterprise was the (Crystal-provided) default scheduling tool. Does this sound familiar?

Comment: Gotcha. Unfortunately, it does not.

Answer (score 0):

You can't schedule a report with Crystal Reports.  You need to use a distribution tool.  I'm aware of these options:

- BusinessObjects Enterprise - a multi-tiered server that includes scheduled distribution
- Using Windows AT with a tool like [Crystal Command](http://www.crystaldesk.com/CrystalCommand.htm)
- Using [PsCrystal](https://github.com/craibuc/PsCrystal) to do something similar; it needs a bit more work for this to be functional

[SAP's Crystal Reports Server](http://www54.sap.com/solution/sme/software/analytics/crystal-server/index.html) doesn't appear to support scheduling.